# Unable to add JQuery Mobile in ReactJS - Can't resolve 'jquery-mobile'

Tags: jquery, reactjs, jquery-mobile, npm, phonegap

I am trying to add `JQM` in my `ReactJS` application. What I am doing to add it is:

```
npm install jquery@1.11.1 --save-dev
npm install jquery-mobile --save-dev
```

It adds `JQuery` and `JQM` to the *modules* but the problem is that When I use this in my application as:

```
import $ from 'jquery';
import 'jquery-mobile';
```

It gives me following error in console:

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'jquery-mobile' in '/var/www/html/react/phonegapApp/'

Also When I use to `import JQuery` it's version automatically updates from `^1.11.1` to the latest version `^3.2.1` in **package.json** file as the required version for the `JQM` NPM module should be less then `1.11.1`

Answer (score 0):

You have to import jquery and then use your code inside of componentDidMount like that:

```js
import $ from 'jquery';

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount = () => {
      // Your Jquery code here for ex:
      $('.message a').click(function(){
      $('form').animate({height: "toggle", opacity: "toggle"}, "slow");
      });
  }
```